# How to solve the cookbook naming mismatch between berks and chef-solo?

Tags: chef, chef-solo, berkshelf

Follow-up to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/817519/215599).

Running chef solo:

```
sudo chef-solo -c config.rb -j config.json



Starting Chef Client, version 12.16.42
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["terraform"]

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: terraform

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* terraform

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

Cookbooks installed using berkshelf contain a version postfix

```
user@host ~ $ ls ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/

terraform-0.5.3
```

If terraform-0.5.3 is renamed to terraform and chef-solo is run again, the terraform cookbook is found, but another one cannot be found:

```
Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: build-essential
```

**Attempt to solve the issue**

The issue was solved by removing the postfix version from all the cookbooks that reside in the following directory:

```
user@host ~ $ ls ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/
ark  ark-1.1.0  build-essential-7.0.2  compat_resource  compat_resource-12.16.2  mingw  mingw-1.2.4  ohai  ohai-4.2.2  seven_zip  seven_zip-2.0.2  terraform-0.5.3  windows  windows-2.1.1
```

This approach has some side effects:

1. Every time berks install is run the cookbooks are downloaded again
2. The postfix needs to be removed every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the berkshelf storage folder directly, it's a storage folder. To export in a format that Chef can use, run `berks vendor FOLDERNAME/`.

Comment: `Could not find command "export".`

Comment: Whoops, it's `berks vendor` (`export` is for `chef export`, the equivalent command for Policyfiles).