# Ubuntu 16.04 preseed and puppet code during kickstart

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, puppet-agent

I have created a preseed based automated installation system incl.
a kickstart.

This is working so far fine - either on vm or on usb on nuc or servers.
My main issue now is that i am not able to run the puppet code during this procedure.

puppet is getting installed 
apt-get install puppet in that

How i can run the puppet code during this?
The file will be available on the root of the filesystem of the cd rom path.

Any suggestion/hints will be very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a chef cookbook?](https://serverfault.com/questions/815697/how-to-run-a-chef-cookbook)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a command to run something like this:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
 in-target /bin/bash -c '/path/to/puppet apply /path/to/puppet.pp'; \
 in-target /bin/bash -c 'echo "Some status message"';
```